# How to Change LOGO in Magento 2.3.x

Tags: magento2.3.5-p1

I want to change logo using code,so anyone can have idea then please reply this question.I want to change logo using phtml file.

Comment: you want to using xml file ???

Comment: no i want to add using phtml file

Comment: overwrite the header.phtml file where it is called I guess.

Comment: ya but there is one blog file called